# Pure VRAM information excluding system RAM on Linux status bar

Tags: interface, customization, linux, memory-management

My AMD RX 6600XT has only 8GB of VRAM, but Blender 3.5.0 on Linux (kernel 6.2.9) is displaying 23.6GB. I think it includes system RAM. How can I make Blender show actual VRAM usage only EXCLUDING the system RAM?

[image]